# How to recieve a JSON API over HTTP and capture the data in flask?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to create a webapp with flask in which I am going to recieve some data over an endpoint e.g /api ,like for example an string in json and do the operation based upon the string . 
Is the request going to be a  part of  body or header?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import json
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api', methods=['POST'])
def reverse():
    print(request.data)
    data = request.get_json(silent=True) 
    # print(json.loads(data))
    return jsonify(request.json)


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

The data I am getting is None type in my print and null in return if I send a post reuest using curl

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api -d {"name":"Alice"}
```

Answer (score 1):

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api -d {"name":"Alice"} -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: specify the mimetype of the incoming request to be application/json

Answer (score 0):

json data is typically sent in the body of a HTTP POST or PUT request.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is incomplete, try

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/api -d '{"name":"Alice"}' --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```